# Connecting to Telnet through a macOS program

Tags: macos, telnet

I am currently trying to code an application for a macOS to control an Arduino. To do this I need to be able to access telnet and send string commands to it. Any ideas on how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`telnet` is insecure, inflexible and out of fashion - folks use `ssh` now. There is no longer even a `telnet` client in High Sierra.

Create an empty file called `ssh` in the partition of your SD card called `boot` to get in the first time. Then `ssh` in with:

```
ssh pi@<RASPI-IP-ADDRESS>
```

and password `raspberry`.

Then use:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

to enable `ssh` for future boots.